# Find out which pdf files have missing fonts

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I have 10.000 pdfs, some of which have missing fonts. I have already found out how to add missing fonts to the pdf using ghostscript:

```
>gswin64 -sFONTPATH=path_to_fonts -o path_topdf_2 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDEFSETTINGS=/prepress path_to_pdf
```

However, this also changes pdf files that do not cause any problems and resizes them afterwards. Before I generate 10.000 new pdf's I would like to go through a loop and find out which of the pdf's do not contain a certain font and recreate only these pdf's. Is this possible using ghostscript or a C# library?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `pdffonts.exe` commandline tool from [Xpdf](https://dl.xpdfreader.com/xpdf-tools-win-4.02.zip).

**Sample output:**

```
pdffonts -loc zzz.pdf
Config Error: No display font for 'Symbol'
Config Error: No display font for 'ZapfDingbats'
name                                           type              emb sub uni prob object ID location
---------------------------------------------- ----------------- --- --- --- ---- --------- --------
FPLBLO+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT                  Type 1C           yes yes yes        1362  0 embedded
FPLBNP+TimesNewRomanPSMT                       Type 1C           yes yes yes        1363  0 embedded
FPLCEN+Arial-BoldMT                            Type 1C           yes yes yes        1833  0 embedded
FPLCHN+TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT                Type 1C           yes yes yes        1844  0 embedded
```

Write a script or a `C#` program which calls `pdffonts.exe` for each of your files and checks the output for missing fonts.